# How can I find row matrix indices which contain specific element?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

if i have a=[1 2 3 4;2 3 4 0;1 1 3 4;0 0 0 1] and I want to find rows at least contain 3 element of [1 2 3 4],for instance rows 1,2,3. what can I do it?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) as follows:

```
a=[1 2 3 4;5 6 7 1;2 3 1 7;3 1 1 2]; % matrix
v = [1 2 3]; % desired values
ind = find(all(any(bsxfun(@eq, a, reshape(v,1,1,[])), 2), 3));
```

This reshapes `v` into the third dimension (`reshape(v,1,1,[])`) and compares all values of `a` with all values of `v` (`bsxfun(@eq, ...)`). Then
it selects indices (`find(...)`) of rows such that all desired values (`all(..., 3)`) are present in any of the entries of that row (`any(..., 2)`).

---

To find the row indices that have at least three elements from array `v`, you can sum up the counts corresponding to each row and then perform the detection:

```
n = 3
ind = find(sum(any(bsxfun(@eq, a, reshape(v,1,1,[])), 2), 3)>=n)
```

Comment: thank you Luis. you really helped me

Comment: Hope the edits look okay in response to the edited question :)

Comment: @Divakar Of course, thanks! You have a `bsxfun` detector or what? :-)

Comment: I was just randomly checking out MATLAB questions for the possibility of vectorization ones/ using bsxfun :D